# Unity blend tree in animator not working/jittering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development, topdown

I am using unity version: 2021.3.6f1
I have setup indevidual animations for the player (four-way idle and walk) and I am using two blend trees which the script accesses and changes the variables moveX, moveY and is_idle. I am using the new Unity input system:
[Screenshot of new Unity input system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF7LF.png)
and cinemachine (cinemachine isn't causing problems though).
When I run the script, it has a weird jittering effect as if the animator keeps reseting the animation playback. Below is a video.
[Link to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub7vV.jpg)
Screenshot of the animator:
[Screenshot of the animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7IqH.png)
Here is the code in the player controller:

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;
    public float collissionOffset = 0.05f;
    
    
    
    
    Vector2 inputaxis;
    Vector2 movementInput;
    Vector2 prevMovementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    Animator animator;
    
    
    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollissions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if(movementInput != Vector2.zero){
            bool success = TryMove(movementInput);
    
            if(movementInput != prevMovementInput)  {          
                animator.SetFloat("moveX", movementInput.x);
                animator.SetFloat("moveY", movementInput.y);
                prevMovementInput = movementInput;
            }
    
        
            if(!success){
                success = TryMove(new Vector2(movementInput.x, 0));
    
                if(!success){
                    success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, movementInput.y));
                }
            }
            animator.SetBool("is_idle",false);
        } else {
            //animator.SetBool("is_idle", true);
        }
    
        
    }
    
    
    
    private bool TryMove(Vector2 direction){
        int count = rb.Cast(direction,
                movementFilter,
                castCollissions,
                moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collissionOffset);
    
    
        if(count == 0){
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    void UpdateAnimation_DONT_USE(){
        // this is my origional function that would be called when I didn't have a blend tre
        //animation direction
        if(movementInput.x == 0.00d){
            if(movementInput.y ==1.00d){
                //up
                animator.SetInteger("direction",1);
            }
        }else if(movementInput.x == 1.00d) {
            if(movementInput.y == 0.00d){
                //right
                animator.SetInteger("direction",2);
            }
        }else if(movementInput.x == 0.00d) {
            if(movementInput.y == -1.00d){
                //down
                animator.SetInteger("direction",3);
            }
        }else if(movementInput.x == -1.00d){
            if(movementInput.y == 0.00d){
                //left
                animator.SetInteger("direction",4);
                
            }
        } 
        
    
        
    
    
    }
    
    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue) {
        movementInput =  movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }

}
```

---

[The youtube video I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM)
First, I had lots of transition arrows going from the Any State block to all of the animation phases. When I tried it, the same result occured. I then watched a different youtube video which showed how to use a [blend tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKauseRHFRg)
I still have no idea what the problem is after trying a lot of different things.
If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.
:)

Comment: Can you share your both transitions conditions?

Comment: Can you insert a log inside your checks for !success and share the results?

Comment: My player log is empty but the editor log is huge and I don't know how to check it.  My animation transitions look like this:  https://imgur.com/a/mcK6Sk3

Comment: Just insert a Debug.Log inside the !success testing, I'm thinking that you're making a double movement and this would be causing the jitter

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but where in the script do I put that?

Comment: Inside your if (!success), both of them and one outside too, put this line inside it - Debug.Log($"A: {Time.frameCount}"); - just change the A to something else to allow us to differentiate them

Comment: It does nothing except when I walk into something - it logs the gameobject that it collided with (expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was because I had connected the blend trees to **Any State**!
What happened was that, every frame, it was checking if it was in any state, and scince it was, it repeatedly started the animation from the beginning.

The solution was to connect the two blend trees together instead connecting them to the any state block.

**Entry --> Player_Move <---> Player_Idle**

Thanks for all your help!